Dealing with CORS when using dynamic routes in Vercel
I have set up a small express proxy which is designed to be deployed on Vercel. The user calls the proxy by sending a request to https://<domain>/<url_to_get>, for example https://proxy-domain.org/https://example.org.
The proxy consists of an ExpressJS server which acts as a serverless function. It intercepts all requests using the app.all method. Here's the code:
// api/index.ts

import axios from 'axios';
import express, { Request as ExpressRequest, Response as ExpressResponse } from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

const VERBOSE = true;

const FORBIDDEN_REQ_HEADERS = [
    "host", "x-forwarded-for"
];

const FORBIDDEN_RES_HEADERS = [
    "content-length", "content-encoding", "transfer-encoding", "content-security-policy-report-only", "content-security-policy"
];

const DEFAULT_RES_HEADERS = {
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "access-control-allow-headers": "*",
    "access-control-expose-headers": "*",
    "access-control-allow-methods": "*",
    "access-control-allow-credentials": "true"
};

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

app.all('/*', async (req: ExpressRequest, res: ExpressResponse) => {
    const url = req.path.substring(1);

    // test whether the URL provided as a path is valid or not
    try {
        new URL(url);
    } catch (err: any) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.writeHead(400, { "content-type": "application/json" }).end(JSON.stringify({ error: 'Invalid URL' }));
        return;
    }

    // construction of the headers object with allowed request headers
    const reqHeaders = Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(req.headers)
            .filter(([key]) => !FORBIDDEN_REQ_HEADERS.includes(key.toLowerCase()))
            .map(([key, value]) => [key, Array.isArray(value) ? value.join(', ') : value ?? ''])
    );

    // construction of body as a buffer
    const body = req.method === "GET" || req.method === "HEAD" ? undefined : await new Promise<Buffer>((resolve, reject) => {
        const chunks: Uint8Array[] = [];
        req.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk));
        req.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks)));
        req.on('error', reject);
    });

    if (VERBOSE) {
        console.log(`\n==> Sending ${req.method} request to ${url}`);
        console.log(`> with headers ${JSON.stringify(reqHeaders)}`);
        if (body) {
            try {
                console.log(`> with body ${JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body.toString()))}`);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(`> with body ${body.toString()}`);
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        const proxyResponse = await axios({
            url,
            method: req.method,
            headers: reqHeaders,
            data: body,
            responseType: 'stream',
            validateStatus: (status: number) => true // don't throw an exception on error status
        });

        // construction of response headers object with allowed response headers
        const resHeaders: Record<string, string> = {};
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(proxyResponse.headers)) {
            if (!FORBIDDEN_RES_HEADERS.includes(key.toLowerCase())) {
                resHeaders[key.toLowerCase()] = Array.isArray(value) ? value.join(', ') : value as string;
            }
        }

        // headers like access-control-allow-origin must not be set by the proxy request
        Object.assign(resHeaders, DEFAULT_RES_HEADERS);
        resHeaders['x-url'] = proxyResponse.request.res.responseUrl;

        if (VERBOSE) {
            console.log('\n==> Response received:');
            console.log(`> with url ${resHeaders['x-url']}`)
            console.log(`> with status ${proxyResponse.status}`);
            console.log(`> with headers ${JSON.stringify(resHeaders)}`);
        }

        res.writeHead(proxyResponse.status, resHeaders);
        proxyResponse.data.pipe(res);

    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error(error.message);
        res.writeHead(500, { "content-type": "application/json" }).end(JSON.stringify({ error: error.message }));
    }
});

const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    if (VERBOSE) console.log(`Proxy server is running on port ${PORT}!`);
});

export default app;


The problem is related to CORS. I can send a request to https://proxy-domain.org without a CORS error, but when I try to call https://proxy-domain.org/https://example.org, a CORS issue is thrown:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at
http://proxy-domain.org/https://example.org/.
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 301.

I think this happens because the path is not recognised (as it does not correspond to a file route). Note that this works as expected in a Nodejs script or any browser, but not in the browser console.
Here's my project's tree:
.
├── api
│   └── index.ts
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── README.md
├── tsconfig.json
└── vercel.json

And finally here is my vercel.json configuration file (it maps the / routes to the /api/ routes):
{
  "version": 2,
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "destination": "/api"
    }
  ],
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
          "value": "true"
        },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
          "value": "*"
        },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
          "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT"
        },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
          "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

